Command not found after pip3 install awscli-local / brew install
When I do awscli-local --version, says command not found. When i do pip show awscli-local, it shows that the location is:
/Users/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.12.5/lib/python3.12/site-packages

How do I add this to my path? I tried adding export PATH=$(pyenv root)/shims:$PATH to .bashrc and it still doesnt work. Also tried installing via brew install but same issue.

I think the command might be called awslocal, try running that?

i did still not seen

Does running find /Users/myuser/.pyenv/ -name awslocal reveal the location of the executable? if so you need to add its parent folder to your PATH

add global path or certain path absolute or relative
settings configure local global

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
